# Numpy Matrix with Ctypes

Tags: python, c, numpy, ctypes

I'm trying to pass a numpy 2-dimensional array to a C function using ctypes, but I can't seem to correctly access the values inside the C function.

In Python I pass

```
img.ctypes.data_as(c_int_p) # img is my matrix, a numpy ndarray
```

to the C function, and in the C code I get this as a simple pointer to int (int*). I've also tried getting this as a int**, with no effect.

Using simple arithmetic to get the matrix values (i * N + j) doesn't give me the expected values.

Could someone help me?

Comment: What's the value of `img.dtype`?

Comment: You need to check `assert img.flags.c_contiguous`, and use `ascontiguousarray` if the array is not contiguous